# Background video not working in firefox or IE

Tags: jquery, html, web

I'm using the JQuery plugin 'videoBG' and am having a few problems. Basically what is happening is that the video works offline in all browsers with no problems, but when I check it online, it won't work in FireFox or IE. This tells me that the script is pointing to the correct video but for some  reason is being blocked in FF and IE when online. This was further confirmed when loading offline in IE for the first time. A dialogue box popped up with the message 'IE has blocked certain scripts from loading on the page, will you allow them to continue?' I clicked yes and it worked fine. This webpage also has several sounds that play on load and are mutable via an onclick function on an image. These functions are totally fine in chrome and IE, but in Firefox they do nothing - hopefully someone can help me with this!

The website is www.sweetsunnyvibes.com

EDIT:All my code is within the initial HTML page

Answer (score 1):

You have two `<body>` elements in your html document. I'm not sure but this can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug complains about "HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/plain" is not supported. Load of media resource http://www.sweetsunnyvibes.com/assets/christmas_snow.webm failed.".

Make sure that your webserver provides correct MIME type (video/webm). Link: [How to configure your webserver for webM video and audio files.](http://www.webcoder.de/2010/06/04/how-to-configure-your-webserver-for-webm-video-and-audio-files/)